# OSRM Backend: Same duration and distance for all modes

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I use `Dockerfile` blow to create an image with default pbf preloaded on it.
But I got same duration and distance for all modes: `driving`, `motorcycle`, `foot`:

```
curl -s "http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1/foot/51.44838,34.80697;51.42098,35.60590?steps=false"
curl -s "http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1/motorcycle/51.44838,34.80697;51.42098,35.60590?steps=false"
curl -s "http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1/driving/51.44838,34.80697;51.42098,35.60590?steps=false"
```

```
FROM osrm/osrm-backend:latest

ARG OSM_FILE=iran-latest.osm.pbf
ARG OSRM_FILE=iran-latest.osrm

ENV OSM_FILE=$OSM_FILE
ENV OSRM_FILE=$OSRM_FILE

COPY ./$OSM_FILE $OSM_FILE

RUN osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua $OSM_FILE
RUN osrm-extract -p /opt/foot.lua $OSM_FILE
RUN osrm-extract -p /opt/bicycle.lua $OSM_FILE
RUN osrm-partition $OSRM_FILE
RUN osrm-customize $OSRM_FILE

CMD osrm-routed --algorithm mld $OSRM_FILE

EXPOSE 5000
```

Is there a solution to fix this due to work with all modes?